# Tracking user activity daily for 30 days

Tags: android-activity

Is this a valid and proper design to keep a track of user activity daily for 30 days?

class AddDayNumbersToUserActivitesForTracking < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :user_activities,:day1,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day2,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day3,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day4,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day5,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day6,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day7,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day8,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day9,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day10,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day11,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day12,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day13,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day14,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day15,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day16,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day17,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day18,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day19,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day20,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day21,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day22,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day23,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day24,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day25,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day26,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day27,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day28,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day29,:integer
    add_column :user_activities,:day30,:integer
  end
end

create_table "user_activities", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "challenge_id"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.integer  "steps_covered"
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "day1"
    t.integer  "day2"
    t.integer  "day3"
    t.integer  "day4"
    t.integer  "day5"
    t.integer  "day6"
    t.integer  "day7"
    t.integer  "day8"
    t.integer  "day9"
    t.integer  "day10"
    t.integer  "day11"
    t.integer  "day12"
    t.integer  "day13"
    t.integer  "day14"
    t.integer  "day15"
    t.integer  "day16"
    t.integer  "day17"
    t.integer  "day18"
    t.integer  "day19"
    t.integer  "day20"
    t.integer  "day21"
    t.integer  "day22"
    t.integer  "day23"
    t.integer  "day24"
    t.integer  "day25"
    t.integer  "day26"
    t.integer  "day27"
    t.integer  "day28"
    t.integer  "day29"
    t.integer  "day30"
  end

add_index "user_activities", ["user_id", "challenge_id"], name: "index_user_activities_on_user_id_and_challenge_id"
Reply

Reply as new Topic